# PHP search_array for multi dimension array

Tags: php, arrays, search

how to get the index of a children array for an array look like this:

```
Array
(
    [1000] => Array
        (
            [firstName] => Ori
            [lastName] => Smith
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1001
                    [1] => 1002
                    [2] => 1003
                    [3] => 1004
                    [4] => 1005
                    [5] => 1006
                    [6] => 1007
                    [7] => 1008
                    [8] => 1009
                    [9] => 1010
                )
        )
)
```

so if I give 1009 as the search, it should return 1000.

It does not work with this code:

```
array_search($childrenId, array_column(myArray, 'children'));
```

Comment: I could tell you why that doesn't work. array_column would give you an array inside an array in your example so your array_search wouldn't even find the child id you were looking for. Also, even if you did find the correct children array, I think array_column gives back a zero-based array

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function found [here](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php#100057):

```
function getParentStack($child, $stack) {
foreach ($stack as $k => $v) {
    if (is_array($v)) {
        // If the current element of the array is an array, recurse it and capture the return
        $return = getParentStack($child, $v);

        // If the return is an array, stack it and return it
        if (is_array($return)) {
            return array($k => $return);
        }
    } else {
        // Since we are not on an array, compare directly
        if ($v == $child) {
            // And if we match, stack it and return it
            return array($k => $child);
        }
    }
}

// Return false since there was nothing found
return false;
}
```

I guess you could get the key by `key(getParentStack(1009, $myarr))` or modify the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = array(
    '1000'=>array('children'=>array('1001','1002')),
    '2000'=>array('children'=>array('2001','2002'))
);
$searchValue = 2001;
$keyName = '';

foreach ($result as $key => $row) {
    foreach ($row['children'] as $child) {
        if ($child == $searchValue) {
            $keyName = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
}

echo $keyName;
```